# How to force update/refresh shipping methods on checkout Magento 2

Tags: magento2

how to refresh shipping methods on checkout Magento 2, which js functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://alanstorm.com/refresh-shipping-rates-for-the-magento-2-checkout/

```
requirejs([
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry'
], function(quote, rateRegistry){

    var address = quote.shippingAddress();

    address.trigger_reload = new Date().getTime();

    rateRegistry.set(address.getKey(), null);
    rateRegistry.set(address.getCacheKey(), null);

    quote.shippingAddress(address);
});
```

Comment: How do we know when it finishes ?

Comment: it can be done also like this:
`rateRegistry.set(quoteModel.shippingAddress().getKey(), null); rateRegistry.set(quoteModel.shippingAddress().getCacheKey(), null); require('Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-service').estimateShippingMethod();`

Comment: Is this the only solution?